# How to free myself from Captcha v3?

Tags: html, reactjs, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I implemented captcha v3 to my website, and to see if it was working fine, I filled my contact form multiple times the way a bot would do it. I can no longer use it anymore, so I concluded that it is working, but the bad news, is that I don't know how I can whitelist myself, I cannot use the contact form at all, I am considered a bot by my website.
Any help, please? it is weird that nobody talks about this issue online,

Comment: I don't think it's something you have control over: captcha v3 has its own internal heuristics to determine if you're a bot or not.